# Running an XP application on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have the following issue: my father is using at his job a really old computer, it still has windows xp on. The computer is about to break down, so we decided to get a new one, probably equipped with windows 10. My father uses a specific program that is written in c++ and the manufacturer has told us that the fonts will not be recognizable in versions later than windows 7.

So I want somehow to run this application on windows 10. I am trying to install a virtual box of windows xp and run the application from there, but things seem to be really slow and not practical. I was wondering, is there a better way to do this? Personally I am using Linux mint and wine seems to be running this programme (the fonts are not recognizable, but maybe a modification of wine for older software will solve this?), so I would like to know if there is something similar for windows 10 that could help me out.

PS: this is my first post here, if I am not following any rules on how to ask a question etc, please feel free to edit/ comment about it.

Comment: Here is an article to run XP Mode for Windows 7 in Windows 10>>>>>https://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-add-an-XP-Mode-Virtual-Machine-to-Windows-10-or-8-using-Hyper-V-00770

Comment: @Moab Hello, thanks for your comment but I'm afraid this is pretty much what I have been trying here. Also, the 30 days period of installation is a no-go, I will not be using it and the user cannot perform this installation without help

Comment: Its your only choice, that program will not run in windows 10, it has to run in some sort of virtual machine.

Comment: @Moab Are there not any programs like Wine but for windows and their older versions?

Comment: Have you tested your program. Windows 10 uses same font technology as Windows XP as Windows 2000 and Windows 95 and can even use Win 3.11 fonts.

Comment: @Mark Hello, when I try running it it Windows10 it won't even run (displays an msg about versions etc). With Wine (in Linux Mint) it runs perfectly, but the fonts indeed do not work (the language it should be displaying is Greek, not sure if this is relevant)

Comment: You can use VMware Workstation and run either Windows 7 or Windows XP (or both).  I have both running here very well. Then you can install the program in the virtual machine.  That will work.

Comment: Did you right click the exe file, Properties, Compatibility tab and select XP and Run As Admin. Type `intl.cpl` in Run or command prompt and set your non Unicode language to Greek.

Comment: @Mark I tried that, I still get the same error msg.

Comment: If the language is suppose to be Greek, I assume you have installed the Greek language pack, on the Windows 10 installation.  However, at the end of the day, it sounds like your only option is to run a licensed version of Windows XP within a virtual machine running on Windows 10.  WINE is the only solution on Linux that allows you to run Windows application on Linux, comparability with WINE, is not guaranteed.

Comment: Have you considered a __Mini Windows XP__ ?
Hiren's BootCD: Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/latest-hirens-bootcd-v83-the-king-of-all-boot-cds/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Windows XP mode if you want to run them on Windows XP.
https://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-add-an-XP-Mode-Virtual-Machine-to-Windows-10-or-8-using-Hyper-V-00770

Or, you can right-click on the application and go to properties, then go to compatibility, and you can run it in compatibility mode for Windows XP.

1.
[image: step 1 image]

2.
[image: step 2 image]

3.
[image: step 3 image]

Comment: Note that according to the link you posted, XP mode won't work on Win10 Home. You'd need Win10 Pro.